# How to alias a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, macos, networking

I'm testing client-side Facebook auth locally.

I'm hitting the error

```
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
```

because I'm testing locally, what is the best way to work around this and alias the URL so I can keep testing locally?

I'm using a Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the url on Facebook to localhost works.

Answer (score 0):

In the facebook application you can set a URL in the app tab where the script is being executed. This has to be set if you're working on some external website.

**Reason why:**

If i was to discover the app id of someones app i cannot start posting feeds and whatnot in it's name. You have to be specific with the URL in the application so it will be granted access.

**Edit**
To my knowledge you cannot work local with facebook applications when it comes to JavaScript. You can specify the local URL in the facebook api but i don't think it will go trough without giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, for this I would use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and make use of its [Map Remote](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/) functionality.